# How can I get the default title of the bundle item from a quote, product, or item object?

Tags: magento-1.9

I can get the item's bundle option id using

```
        foreach ($item->getQtyOptions() as $optionQty) {
            $optionId = $optionQty->getOptionId();
        }
```

but I am having a hard time getting the default title. Do you have any idea how to retrieve the default title? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this problem using

```
$optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($product);
```